# How to check if string contains excactly 2 substrings

Tags: php, string, boolean, substring

```
$string = "/*123123123*/";
$string = "123/*123123*/";
$string = "/*123123*/123";
$string = "123/*123123*/123";
```

for all these variants, I need to return true, so /* and */ are present in string.

Tried

```
if(preg_match("/(/*&*/)/i", $string)){ 

          $flag=true;
       }
       else{
           $flag=false;
       }
```

but it didn't work out :c

Comment: Just use `strpos`

Answer (score 0):

Use substr_count(): http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr-count.php

> int substr_count ( string $haystack , string $needle [, int $offset = 0 [, int $length ]] )

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
if (preg_match('%/\*.+\*/%', $string)) {
    $flag = true;
} else {
    $flag = false;
}
```

---

[Regex Demo and Explanation](https://regex101.com/r/Kf3R76/1)

Comment: look at my answer please (:

Comment: Should be made lazy `.+?` otherwise it freaks out on something like `/* comment */ code /* comment */ would take the whole thing unless its really just about the if  both are in

Answer (score 0):

I used

```
if((strpos($string,"/*")!== FALSE) && (strpos($string,"*/")!== FALSE)){
           $flag=true;
       }
       else{
          $flag=false;
       }
```

Don't actually know what is better to use, code above, or code with regexp by Pedro Lobito:

```
if (preg_match('%/\*.+\*/%', $string)) {
    $flag = true;
} else {
    $flag = false;
}
```

Comment: What works better is all up to you. Unless your writing some highly visited code I woudn't worry to much about what performs better. These both should execute in fine time. Focus on what is easier for you to understand if you look back at it a few weeks, months or even years from now. Personally  id pic opt #1 as its a bit easier on the eyes to read then regex (even though this one is super simple)

Comment: Also if you really want to save on space you can use something like `$flag = (strpos($string,"/*")!== FALSE) && (strpos($string,"*/")!== FALSE);` As that will return true or false just as it does in the if